# Ошибка Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, строки

Передо мной постала простая задача в заданой строке вставить некоторое 
 количество пробелов между словами чтобы длина строки была 60 символов. Но 
 при запуске выдается ошибка "stack around the variable 's' was corrupted". 
 Кто  может подсказать в чем проблема?

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string.h>
 using namespace std;
 void change(char arr[61][130], char s[61], int i) {
 int k = 0;
 while (strlen(s)<60) {
    if (k == i - 1) k = 0;
    strcat_s(arr[k], sizeof arr[k], " ");
    memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
    strcat_s(s, sizeof arr[j], arr[j]);
    k++;
     }
   printf("%s","A new string: ");
   printf("%s\n", s);
 }

void break_on_array(char s[61]) {
char*p;
char*np = NULL;
char*delim = " ";
int i = 0;
char arr[61][130];
p = strtok_s(s, delim, &np);
while (p != NULL) {
    strcpy_s(arr[i], sizeof arr[i], p);
    p = strtok_s(NULL, delim, &np);
    i++;
   }
    change(arr, s, i);
}

int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
 char s[61];
 printf("%s\n", "Введите строку: ");
 gets_s(s);
 break_on_array(s);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какой же это "с", если `iostream` да `namespace std`?...

Comment: На каком языке это написано? `#include<iostream>` - это С++. Но в С++ нельзя `char*delim = " ";`.

Comment: @AnT, "Но в С++ нельзя `char*delim = " ";`". Должно быть `const char *delim = " ";`?

Comment: @wololo: Да, например так.

Comment: @AnT, Эх, попробовал скомпилировать небольшой [примерчик](https://ideone.com/dRskQY) с `char` заместо `const char` — а он таки взял и скомпилировался. Хотя стандарт говорит, что тип строкового литерала это "array of _n_ `const char`”...

Comment: @wololo: Ну так вы, надеюсь, знаете, что в C++98/C++03 существовала специально для таких случаев заведенная конверсия из string literal в `char *`. В С++11 эту конверсию выкосили нафиг, но некоторые компиляторы до сих пор поддерживают ее в режиме совместимости. Это, однако, не повод так делать в С++ коде. Да и в С коде следует избегать указания на строковые литералы через `char *`. А уж ideone - это вообще профанация. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c328322d8058fb56

Answer (score 2):

Отладочная версия функции `strcat_s` при каждом вызове заполняет неиспользованный остаток буфера значением `0xFD`, вплоть до указанного размера

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx

> The debug versions of these functions first fill the buffer with 0xFD. To disable this behavior, use _CrtSetDebugFillThreshold.

Поэтому если вы "наврете" функции `strcat_s` про размер вашего буфера в большую сторону, то произойдет запись значения `0xFD` за пределы буфера, даже если соединяемые вам строки прекрасно помещаются в целевой буфер.

У вас в коде вы явно "врете" про размер вашего буфера: размер буфера равен `61`, а вы передаете в `strcat_s` значение `sizeof arr[j]`, т.е. `130`. При первом же вызове `strcat_s` происходит уничтожение содержимого стека за пределами `s`, независимо от того, какие у вас входные данные.

Такое поведение `strcat_s` сделано специально для того, чтобы как можно раньше выявлять ошибки, вроде вашей.

Вот и все.

---

**P.S.** Если вы в начале вашей программы сделаете `_CrtSetDebugFillThreshold(0);`, то ошибка "исчезнет", ибо фактического выхода за пределы буфера в вашем коде (при "разумном" входе) не происходит. Однако это, разумеется, профанация. Если уже вы взялись пользоваться функциями группы `_s`, то пользуйтесь ими правильно.

**P.P.S.** Внутри функции `change` переменная `s` имеет тип `char *` и, соответственно, `sizeof(s)` является просто размером указателя. Поэтому ваше

```
memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
```

довольно бессмысленное действие. Это "работает", но с таким же успехом можно было сделать просто `*s = 0`. Применение `memset` тут не дает ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите внимательно на синтаксис [gets_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets)

```
char *gets_s( char *str, rsize_t n );
```

там два параметра, а не один. Поэтому, вызывать нужно хотя бы так

```
gets_s(s, 60);
```

Comment: Вряд ли у него на входе строка длиннее 60 символов...

Comment: это не имеет никакого значения. Это же си, а не с++:) Хотя душок с++ есть:)

Comment: Ну да. С `iostream` и `using namespace...`. Это С++... И компилирует он 100% в режиме С++.

Comment: да, я видел. Но где использование? да и код написан на си. Но я не раз замечал от студийного компилятора, что он не ругается на отсутствие параметров в `_s` функциях, но падает как и положено

Comment: @KoVadim: Студийный компилятор всегда исправно ругается на отсутствующие параметры в `_s` функциях, когда эти параметры нужны. Вы, очевидно, рассматривали использование `_s` функций в С++ коде, где они были перегружены шаблонами, подставляющими отсутствующие параметры.

Comment: я точно такое выдел с некоторыми `_s` функциями в 2012 или 2013 студии. И даже добавлением параметра-размера фиксил "странное падение"